# Shadow inside table view cell not working

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode

The shadow in my cell is not working at all.

This is one of the view that I want to add shadow but it's not working. I added this code inside my custom cell class.

```
        super.layoutSubviews()
        
        
        
        
        UIview1.layer.cornerRadius = 7
        UIview1.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
        UIview1.layer.borderColor = HexColor.hexStringToUIColor(hex: "FA2537").cgColor
        UIview1.layer.masksToBounds = true
        
        UIview1.layer.shadowColor = HexColor.hexStringToUIColor(hex: "01A4B7").cgColor
        UIview1.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
        UIview1.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize.zero
        UIview1.layer.shadowRadius = 5
        
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

For showing shadow on a view, you need to set its layer's **masksToBounds** property `false`.

or you can try this.

You can make a method like this and can use:

```
 extension UIView {
    
    func setShadowWith(color: UIColor = UIColor.black, shadowOpacity: Float = 0.2, radius: Float = 1.0, shadowOffSet: CGSize = CGSize(width: 0, height: 1)) {
        self.layer.shadowColor = color.cgColor
        self.layer.shadowOpacity = shadowOpacity
        self.layer.shadowOffset = shadowOffSet
        self.layer.shadowRadius = CGFloat(radius)
    }
}
```

and can use function like:

```
yourContainerView.setShadowWith()
```

Here parameters used in functions are taking default values. you can change accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Set **maskToBounds** to `false` instead of `true`:

```
UIview1.layer.masksToBounds = false
```